# Taking json data and converting it to a CSV file

Tags: ruby, json, csv

Okay... so new to Ruby here but loving it so far. My problem is I cannot get the data to go into the CSV files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'date'
require_relative 'amf'
require 'json'
require 'csv'

amf = Amf.new
#This makes it go out 3 days
apps = amf.post( 'Appointments.getBetweenDates',
             { 'startDate' => Date.today, 'endDate' => Date.today + 4 }
)

apps.each do |app|
cor_md_params = { 'appId' => app['appID'], 'relId' => 7 }
cor_md = amf.post( 'Clinicians.getByAppIdAndRelId', cor_md_params ).first


#this is where it breaks ----->
CSV.open("ile.csv", "wb") do |csv|
csv << ["column1", "column2", "etc.", "etc.."]

csv << ([

# if added puts ([ I can display the info and then make a csv...
  app['patFirstName'],
  app['patMiddleName'],
  app['patLastName'],
  app['patBirthdate'],
  app['patHin'],
  app['patPhone'],
  app['patCellPhone'],
  app['patBusinessPhone'],
  app['appTime'],
  app['appID'],
  app['patPostalCode'],
  app['patProvince'],
  app['locName'],

  # note that this is not exactly accurate for follow-ups,
  # where you have to replace the "1" with the actual value
  # in weeks, days, months, etc
  #app[ 'bookName' ], => not sure this is needed

  cor_md['id'],
  cor_md['providerCode'],
  cor_md['firstName'],
  cor_md['lastName']


].join(', '))

end
end
```

Now, if I remove the attempt to make the ile.cvs file and just output it with a puts, all the data shows. But I don't want to have to go into the terminal and create a csv file... I would rather just run the .rb program and have it created. Also, hopefully I am making the columns correctly as well...

The thought occurred to me that I could just add another puts above the output.
Or, better, insert a row into the array before I output it...

Really not sure what is best practice here and standards.

This is what I have done and attempted. How can I get it to cleanly output to a CSV file since my attempts are not working

Also, to clarify where it breaks, it does add the column names just not the JSON info that is parsed. I could also be completely doing this the wrong way or a way that isn't possible. I just do not know.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of error do you get? Is it this one:

`<<': undefined method`map' for "something":String (NoMethodError)

I think, you should remove the .join(', ')
The << method of CSV accepts an array, but not a String

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-3C-3C

So instead of:

```
  cor_md['lastName']
].join(', '))
```

rather:

```
  cor_md['lastName']
])
```

2. The problem with the loop (why it writes only 1 row of data)

In the body of your loop, you always reopen the file, and always rewrite what you added before. What you want to do, is probably this:

```
CSV.open("ile3.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["column1", "column2", "etc.", "etc.."]
  apps.each do |app|
    cor_md_params = { 'appId' => app['appID'], 'relId' => 7 }
    cor_md = amf.post( 'Clinicians.getByAppIdAndRelId', cor_md_params ).first
    #csv << your long array
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah! That worked but the problem now is that I only get 1 row of data so looks like I need a bit more work to do to get all of the data output... possible loop.. not sure...